# codedui test adding a record causes duplicate record error on playback

Tags: coded-ui-tests

Sooo, I am new to codedui so I may need some hand holding. I have a web application. It is like a customer service app. So I add a record, in this case I am adding an institution and there are 5 required fields, 2 of the fields are ID numbers. When I playback the recording, I will error out on the first ID becasue it is trying to add an inst with an existing ID (the same will happen on the second ID if I bypass the first.

Unfortunately, I cannot delete the institution.

So can I add code that will increase the Institution ID each time the test runs? If so, what is the code I need and where do I add it?

***This is from the CodedUITest.cs***

```
[TestMethod]
        public void CodedUITestMethod1()
        {
            // Add a new Institution

            this.UIMap.NavToInst_and_Add_Inst();

        }

***This is the the definition in the UIMap.Designer.cs***

 // Type '99999' in '* Institution ID:' text box
            uIInstitutionIDEdit.Text = this.NavToInst_and_Add_InstParams.UIInstitutionIDEditText;

***And when I go to definition from 'UIInstitutionIDEditText' I get this***

 /// <summary>
        /// Type '99999' in '* Institution ID:' text box
        /// </summary>
        public string UIInstitutionIDEditText = "99999";
```

I hope I have covered everything, thanks so much for any help you can provide. I have searched for an answer but haven't had any luck. I am also not a coder.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

What ever API your using to add an entry you'll need to check what the biggest number currently used is and assign it to the variable you intend to let `CodedUI` to assign to the text box.

*some liberty used to to illustrate*

```
 var highestUsedId = // your production code for looking up highest ID
 UIMap.UIWindow.UIDocument.UIInstitutionIDEditText = (highestUsedId + 1).ToString();
 UIMap.NavToInst_and_Add_Inst();
```